# "It doesn't work on all platforms"?

Tags: meaning

> The file doesn't work on all platforms

Does it mean "Not every platform does the file work", which means that the file works only on some platforms, not every platform.

Or does it mean "the file doesn't work on any platform"? If it means the latter one, is there any reason to use "all" instead of "any"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the file is not guaranteed to work across every conceivable platform. For example, if we were to take the three dominant PC platforms (Windows, macOS, Linux), the file might work across Windows and Linux but not macOS.